# How to fix a reverse function?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to fix a reverse function that it seems to work wrong. After checking the body of the function I noticed that it seems to a section has been deleted or somethig like this by someone. I was trying to add the the missing information but python return me a type error with an unsupported operand type(s) for +. I think that I am on the wrong track cause I cannot use + or - operand to fixe it.

Any help is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

This is the body which I cannot modified at all except that "i" part

```
def reverse(s):
 '''(str) -> str

    Return the reverse of s.

     >>> reverse('abc')
    'cba'
     >>> reverse('a')
    'a'
     >>> reverse('madam')
    'madam'
     >>> reverse('1234!')
    '!4321'
    '''

    result = ''
    i = len(s) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        result = result + s[i]
        i =  i + s # This part it seems to be problematic. The rest work properly  

    return result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `i` is an integer. The variable `s` is a string. It makes no sense to add an integer to string.

In the variable `i` you track the current character number. You start by going from the last character (right-most) to the first character (left-most). `i` tracks this character number. That means you have to update the `i` in every iteration by reducing it.

Use this line instead:

```
i = i - 1
```